# В Gitlab не отображается кнопка New Branch

Tags: git, git-branch, gitlab

В проекте на Gitlab понадобилось создать свою ветку для того, чтобы залить изменения, но в браузере кнопки New Branch нет, хотя судя по справке она должна быть.
[image: Отсутствие кнопки]

В чём может быть причина, недостаточно прав пользователя?

Comment: git checkout -b new_branch и запушить пробовали?

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev да, пробовал. Создал новую ветку но запушить не удаётся. Пишет: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: создал новый remote upstream, но с ним такая же история

Comment: Тогда, по всей видимости, действительно недостаточно прав

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Откройте в вашем проекте `/project_members` и посмотрите на свой уровень доступа. Для создания веток он должен быть не ниже, чем Developer.

http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html#project

Если прав не хватает, то можно запросить доступ прямо через интерфейс GitLab. Вернитесь на страницу проекта. Там есть кнопка "Request Access":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И правда. Прав не хватает. "You have Reporter access to this project" написано на странице проекта. Правда кнопки Request Access нет, видимо она только для тех, кто вообще не допущен. Спасибо!